# SSIS - insert system date variable as a execute sql task parameter

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012

I am trying to insert the `system:starttime` variable into a table by passing a parameter into an execute sql task.

I dont have much knowledge of SSIS data types, and I am currently having trouble making this functionality work. When I set the parameters datatype to `nvarchar`, the date is always inserted as 1/1/1900. When I use the `DBDATE` type, the insert fails with the following error

```
unsupported data type on parameter binding 0
```

So my question is how do I pass a SSIS date variable into an execute sql task so that SQL Server can interpret it correctly?

Comment: Perfect answer here http://blog.hoegaerden.be/2011/06/11/passing-a-datetime-parameter-into-the-execute-sql-task/

Comment: @aasim.abdullah: It would be a good idea to summarize the content of that link in an answer, that way if the link dies at a later date (and StackExchange doesn't) the information is still available here. Include the link in the answer of course for people who want more detail and for giving credit to the source.

Comment: @aasim.abdullah - Thanks for the link, as recommended I tried using the "DATE" datatype (not "DBDATE") and it worked like a charm!

Comment: @David sure buddy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [BOL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141036.aspx) `DT_DBDATE` is *"A date structure that consists of year, month, and day"*. Which can't be used to store `System::StartTime` output as its `DATETIME` by data type, so try to use datatype `DT_DATE` instead of `DBDATE`. As datatype DT_DATE *"A date structure that consists of year, month, day, hour, minute, seconds, and fractional seconds. The fractional seconds have a fixed scale of 7 digits."*